# Superconductors and hoverboards

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, levitation, technology

We know that superconductors are repelled by magnetic fields. The earth has a magnetic field of about $10^{-5}$ Tesla. I just want to know if it is possible to use this property of earth to make hover-boards and levitating cars which actually work everywhere and not just some artificial environment. Would it be possible to use such small amount of magnetic field to generate a high enough repulsive force ,just by induction, which could support our bodies?

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no net force on a superconductor in a homogeneous magnetic field. How would the superconductor know which way to go? That one can levitate magnets and superconductors in the lab is because the field is not homogeneous. Even if the field was inhomogeneous, I am afraid, it would be too weak by several orders of magnitude. Technological levitation of e.g. the Transrapid and the Japanese Maglev trains happens at several hundred thousands times the magnetic field strength of Earth's field.

Comment: @CuriousOne If we apply a force in a particular direction, then shouldn't some current be induced in superconductor making variations in magnetic field? But the current will oppose change in motion. I guess you're right. :|

Comment: The superconductor basically squeezes the magnetic field out of its volume, i.e. the field energy is reduced in its volume to zero and slightly raised in the rest of the volume, which basically gives rise to a potential. If the field is homogeneous, this is independent of where the superconductor is, i.e. the potential is constant. A constant potential equals zero net force. Another way of seeing this is by looking at the pressure on the superconductor: it's the same from each side, leaving it under stress but motionless.